# Ensure validity of multiple hierarchies in Oracle table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm storing multiple hierarchies within an Oracle table (standard model of parent, child, root columns) and was interested in finding out what constraints I should consider to make sure the hierarchy remains correct and valid.

I'd like to ensure that for each row the child, parent and root columns all make sense (eg. the same root can not be defined for two different hierarchies, if a child exists so does it's parent, etc.)

I know from working with linked tables that were defined with no constraints (!!) inconsistent/incomplete data *always* creeps in one way or another no matter how carefully the application tries to avoid it.

Now considering triggers should generally be avoided for all but the simple cases and I can't see how to code a constraint for this, is a stored procedure the only real way to go (presumably with a serializable transaction mode set)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not define foreign key referring the same table of the constraint in the CREATE TABLE statement, but you could do it with an ALTER TABLE statement.

```
create table XXX (
    key number primary key,
    parent number
)
/

alter table XXX add constraint XXX_FK foreign key (parent) references XXX
/
```

Comment: You can do that in a single command, but you need to explicitly reference the primary key column.  For example: `,constraint xxx_fk foreign key (parent) references xxx(key)`.